# SQLite database wont update with a Python variable

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

I tried to update (add) the integer value of a cell named "product_qty" in a table in an SQLite database with a variable, with the following lines of code

```
x = int(TOPUPQTY.get())
cursor.execute("UPDATE 'product' SET product_qty = product_qty + x WHERE `product_name` LIKE ?", ('%'+str(TOPUPPRODUCT_NAME.get())+'%',))
```

I got an `sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: x`.
But when I tried substituting the variable `x` with a constant say `30`, that is:

```
cursor.execute("UPDATE 'product' SET product_qty = product_qty + 30 WHERE `product_name` LIKE ?", ('%'+str(TOPUPPRODUCT_NAME.get())+'%',))
```

this worked very well, but i need to use a variable instead of a constant.

Comment: Please separate your code from the text. This makes it better readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a placeholder "?" for the variable in the string.

```
x = 30
cursor.execute(f"UPDATE product SET product_qty = product_qty + ? WHERE product_name LIKE ?", (x, '%'+str(TOPUPPRODUCT_NAME.get())+'%',))
```

You should NOT put x in the string yourself e.g. with a formatting string, as then you have the possibility to get an sql-injection if the contents of x comes from an untrusted source. So better always rely on the formatting from the sqlite package itself.

Comment: That's the way to go. I suggested an answer with string formatting because I wasn't sure that placeholders would work here but I checked it and everything is fine.

Answer (score 2):

You have written variable *x* inside **double-quotes** and when the cursor statement executes it tries to find column *x* in the table and that's why the error occurs.

You have to pass the variable's value to the query using a placeholder.